Declaring an interface property as a derived type
Currently I have a series of services/repos that are allowing a generic of a custom type. I want to add a generic list to that interface such that when a class inherits the interface it can apply a type that is derived from the generic type of the list. The example I thought up is a Building with a list of vehicles. I want to be able to, inside the declaration of a building, say the list is of type "Car" Here is some sample code:
public interface IBuilding<T>: ThirdPartyItem where T : IVehicle
{
    public List<T> SubItems { get; set; }
}

public interface IVehicle: ThirdPartyItem
{
   public string Name{ get; }
}
public class Car: IVehicle
{
   public string Name{ get; }
}


public class Hospital: IBuilding<Car>
{
    public List<Car> SubItems { get; set; }
}

This works as is but when I try to call my services there are issues, here is the sample code:
    public int CopyData<T> () where T : IBuilding<IVehicle>, new(){}

   int res = _genericService.CopyData<Hospital>();

The issue is in the syntax when calling CopyData, "There is no implicit reference conversion from "Hospital" to "IBuilding".
I have other instances calling copydata whose classes are defined with direct reference to IVehicle rather then an explicit type, those all work. But for this instance I need to be able to declare an explicit type for later in the code.

Are you sure you've provided the complete error message? As far as I can tell, you don't have a class called IBuilding (You do have an IBuilding<Car> but that is a different type).
